# Is there a more dynamic way of loading pages?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I am fairly new to NodeJS, and have some knowledge in JavaScript. I am creating a Discord-like web application for some fun. I have 2 different pages so for using EJS: home.ejs and server.ejs.

My home.ejs shows 4 sections (sidebar, mid sidebar, main content and right sidebar), this shows friends, messages etc, where the far left shows server icons.

When clicking a server icon, the following code is used:

```
const serverIcon = document.querySelector(".server-icon");

  // Attach a click event listener to the homeIcon
  serverIcon.addEventListener("click", function () {
    fetch("/server")
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((htmlContent) => {
        document.open();
        document.write(htmlContent);
        document.close();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  });
```

It then loads the server.ejs document, but for a brief second, there is a blank page before loading it. Same thing goes for clicking the home icon, it loads home.ejs and gives a blank page briefly.

```
 const homeIcon = document.querySelector(".home-icon");

  // Attach a click event listener to the homeIcon
  homeIcon.addEventListener("click", function () {
    fetch("/")
      .then((response) => response.text()) 
      .then((htmlContent) => {
        document.open();
        document.write(htmlContent);
        document.close();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  });
```

Basically what I am wondering, is if there is a smoother way to do this making the loading seamless.

The code provided is the only method I can think of. Wondering if it would be more seamless if I loaded parts instead of views.

Comment: Well, you are doing almost full page refreshes. If you want to get rid of the 'white flash', one thing you can look at is the experimental [view transition api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/View_Transitions_API), but ultimately the best solution is to *not* re-render the whole page and only update things that have actually changed.